# Spark dataframe join is failing if key column contains a period(".") in the end

Tags: scala, apache-spark, inner-join

I am getting below exception if I do join in between two dataframes in spark (ver 1.5, scala 2.10).

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: syntax error in attribute name: col1.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedAttribute$.e$1(unresolved.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedAttribute$.parseAttributeName(unresolved.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveQuoted(LogicalPlan.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.resolve(DataFrame.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.col(DataFrame.scala:653)
    at com.nielsen.buy.integration.commons.Demo$.main(Demo.scala:62)
    at com.nielsen.buy.integration.commons.Demo.main(Demo.scala)
```

Code works fine if column in dataframe does not contain any period . Please do help me out.

You can find the code that I am using.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import com.google.gson.Gson
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

object Demo
{
lazy val sc: SparkContext = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local")
      .setAppName("demooo")
      .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
    new SparkContext(conf)
  } 
  sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  lazy val sqlcontext=new SQLContext(sc)

val data=List(Row("a","b"),Row("v","b"))
        val dataRdd=sc.parallelize(data)
        val schema =  new StructType(Array(StructField("col.1",StringType,true),StructField("col2",StringType,true)))
        val df1=sqlcontext.createDataFrame(dataRdd, schema)

        val data2=List(Row("a","b"),Row("v","b"))
        val dataRdd2=sc.parallelize(data2)
        val schema2 =  new StructType(Array(StructField("col3",StringType,true),StructField("col4",StringType,true)))
        val df2=sqlcontext.createDataFrame(dataRdd2, schema2)
        val val1="col.1"
        val df3= df1.join(df2,df1.col(val1).equalTo(df2.col("col3")),"outer").show
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, period is used to access members of a struct field.
The spark version you are using (1.5) is relatively old. Several such issues were fixed in later versions so if you upgrade it might just solve the issue.

That said, you can simply use withColumnRenamed to rename the column to something which does not have a period before the join.
So you basically do something like this:

```
val dfTmp = df1.withColumnRenamed(val1, "JOIN_COL")
val df3= dfTmp.join(df2,dfTmp.col("JOIN_COL").equalTo(df2.col("col3")),"outer").withColumnRenamed("JOIN_COL", val1)
df3.show
```

btw show returns a Unit so you probably meant df3 to be equal to the expression without it and do df3.show separately.

Comment: thanks.. previously i used to replace dot in all the col names and create a new dataframe. in turn it was demanding for converting dataframe to rdd which was an unneccesarry action. then i finaly realised after your reply that only key column has to be get rid of dot. thanks